# Bootstrap: Align button adjacent to the textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the button on the right to fit adjacent to the email textbox.

But, it is not working for me.

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/Vimalan/mt30tfpv/4/

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="RequestorNameTxtBox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="RequestorEmailTxtBox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label></label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="RequestorLookupBtn">Lookup</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Expectation:**

[image]

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="RequestorNameTxtBox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="RequestorEmailTxtBox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <button type="button" class="form-control input-sm btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="RequestorLookupBtn">Lookup</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a 'margin-top' style to the button

`<button style="margin-top:25px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="RequestorLookupBtn">Lookup</button>`